# TortoiseGit - how to review all changes in a branch

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have used several version control systems over my career - ClearCase, PVCS, SCCS, Perforce, CVS, SourceSafe - but never used a distributed system before.

For the first time, I am using a distributed system - Git. It's been weeks - but I cannot make head nor tail of how to do stuff.

A colleague create a branch and worked on a small feature in the branch. I now want to review all the changes he made in that branch. How do I do this in TortoiseGit (I have hooked up TortoiseGit to Windiff).

Is there a way to see a windiff of all changes done on that branch? What are the steps?

Comment: My recommendation - forget about TortoiseGit, it is horrible. Use the command line.

Comment: [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a really really nice book.

Comment: Also forget all the knowledge you had before about **central** version control system.

Answer (score 9):

Soppuse your colleague pushed his commits to remote, and you fetched it from the remote. You are on master branch, and also made some changes but not push it to remote, yet. Then, the **Show log** shows you something looks like this: (Right click on root of repository -> TortoiseGit -> Show log. Make sure the `All Branches` checkbox is checked.)

[image]

As you can see, your colleague added 2 commits. Also you can see there is fork point(commit) which its hash(SHA-1) is **b6f7e84** and has a remote-tracking branch **origin/master** on it. Then you can select the following two revisions by using **Ctrl + Mouse Left Key**.

[image]

Then, right click on one of those two commits and click **Compare revisions**
(you can compare any two commits this way)

[image]

TortoiseGit shows you this dialog to list all changed files between those 2 commits:

[image]

Double click on the file you want to reivew, for eample: on 1.txt, the built-in TortoiseGitMerge will shows you:

[image]

If you don't want to use TortoiseGitMerge for showing diff, you can setup other diff tool which support the command line. See [External Program Settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-progs) for more infomation. There are some examples for *ExamDiff*, *KDiff3*, *WinMerge*, *Araxis*, but *Windiff*. (If you figure it out, please tell me, perhaps I could put it on TortoiseGit manual.)

---

If you want to see the changes of each commit. Just double click the file in log dialog. See:

[image]